# Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated

Tags: php

I am struggling with the following error in my OO PHP code:

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

This is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/product.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare product object
$product = new Product($db);

// get id of product to be edited
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 

// set ID property of product to be edited
$product->id = $data->id;

// read the details of product to be edited
$product->readOne();

// create array
$product_arr[] = array(
    "id" =>  $product->id,
    "name" => $product->name,
    "description" => $product->description,
    "price" => $product->price
);

// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($product_arr));
?>
```

I have tried the updating *php.ini* file and it does not work...

Comment: why not use `$_POST` ??

Comment: i have tried but still get the error

Comment: tried what exactly? what error?

Comment: Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  --> i get this error

Comment: Instead of using $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); i have used $data = $_POST['id'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry thanks you were right :)

`$_REQUEST['id']` -> took away the error

// get id of product to be edited

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

replaced  `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`  this with this `$_REQUEST['id']`

Comment: i suggest `$_POST` .. instead of `$_REQUEST`